# PHP сравнить два массива объектов

Tags: php

Есть два массива с именами. Записать в третий массив имена которые совпадают из первого и второго массива.

```
Array(
  [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [login] => serg123

    )

  [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [login] => turb0

    )
```

)

```
Array(
   [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [login] => Maksim

    )

   [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [login] => turb0

    )
```

)

в третьем массиве должно быть

```
Array(
     [0] => stdClass Object
(
    [login] => turb0

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Давайте воспользуемся функцией array_intersect - которая возвращает совпадения значений в массивах. Для начала надо избавиться от объектов в массивах. Для каждого массива делаем так

```
$arr1 = array();
foreach($arr_source_1 as $o) {
   $arr1[] = $o->login;
}
```

аналогично получим $arr2 для второго массива

Далее находим пересечение этих массивов

```
$arr_int = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);
```

и формируем результирующий массив

```
$arr_res = array();
foreach ($arr_int as $v) {
   $o = new stdClass();
   $o->login = $v;
   $arr_res[] = $o;
}
```

Comment: Привет. Спасибо. Я изменил вопрос.

Comment: @Maksim так делать нельзя

Comment: Извините я запутался и не то спросил